# Generic type implementation of linked list and swapping two generic objects

Tags: java, generics, interface, comparable

### Generic class implementing Comparable

My first question is how to correctly implement a Generic class that implements compareTo. My current class definition is:

```
public static class Node<T> implements Comparable<Node<T>>{
```

and my compareTo method is:

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> int compareTo(Node<T> n){
```

1a. Are these definitions correct?

1b. How should I complete my compareTo method? Much of the literature I have found online has referenced using .compareTo() within the method itself, which does not make sense to me.

### Swap two nodes in linked list:

My current method definition is

```
public void swap(Node<T> n1, Node<T> n2){
    // swap
}
```

2. Is it possible to swap two nodes in a singly linked list implementation, or does the swap method inherently require a doubly linked implementation of a linked list?

Comment: How are you supposed to use `compareTo` here? E.g. to sort the list...? Or...? What are you comparing?

Comment: You have two unrelated questions here.  Consider making separate questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1a. Are these definitions correct?

Not completely. The definition you have for `compareTo` is declaring a type variable and this is probably wrong:

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> int compareTo(Node<T> n){
```

(It actually shouldn't compile.)

It should just be:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Node<T> n){
```

> 1b. How should I complete my compareTo method?

That depends on what you're supposed to be comparing. Since you haven't specified, we don't know. ; )

> Much of the literature I have found online has referenced using .compareTo() within the method itself, which does not make sense to me.

Here's an example of how this would typically be used:

```
// saying T must also be Comparable:
// it's possible you are supposed to do
// this for your own Node declaration too
//         vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Node<T>> {
    T data;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node<T> that) {
        return this.data.compareTo( that.data );
    }
}
```

Now we can compare nodes, but it actually delegates to whatever the data is. We don't know or care what the data is (though it can't be null), just that it implements `Comparable`.

> 2. Is it possible to swap two nodes in a singly linked list implementation, or does the swap method inherently require a doubly linked implementation of a linked list?

The hint here is that you don't need to swap nodes, just whatever their data is.

Answer (score 0):

> My current class definition is:

```
public static class Node<T> implements Comparable<Node<T>>{
```

> and my compareTo method is:

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> int compareTo(Node<T> n){
```

> 1a. Are these definitions correct?

The class declaration looks fine.  Not so much the `compareTo()` method.  By specifying a type parameter on the method (`<T extends Comparable<T>>`) you are declaring a generic method, which is a different beast from an ordinary method that happens to rely on the *class's* type parameter.  You want this, instead:

```
public int compareTo(Node<T> n){
```

> 1b. How should I complete my compareTo method? Much of the literature I have found online has referenced using .compareTo() within the method itself, which does not make sense to me.

You implement the method in whatever way makes sense, based on the fields of your `Node` class.  If it's unclear to you what would make one `Node` less than another, then the class probably shouldn't be implementing `Comparable`.

Your confusion about use of `.compareTo()` is evident in the question itself.  `compareTo()` is not meaningful as a method name outside the context of a particular class.  There are a great many such methods, all different.  In many cases it is sensible to use the `compareTo()` method of one class in the implementation of the `compareTo()` method of a *different* class.

> 2. Is it possible to swap two nodes in a singly linked list implementation, or does the swap method inherently require a doubly linked implementation of a linked list?

It is possible to swap nodes in a singly-linked list.  You might be able to swap just payloads, but if it is essential to swap the node objects themselves then you'll need to traverse the list to find each node's preceding node.  Depending on details of your data structure, you might need special handling when one of the nodes to swap is the first in the list.